# How to save PDFs from assets/www folder via XHR to Filesystem in Cordova?

Tags: ios, pdf, cordova

I am trying to get a PDF displaying in Cordova iOS (and potentially later Android) using PDFjs. It seems that PDFjs needs the files served from a webserver in order to use its normal load function but it will accept a PDF encoded as a Uint8Array.

I have attempted to use Cordova's `FileAPI` which has methods for loading to Uint8Array to load the PDF which can load from the `Documents` folder but from what I can tell the API appears not have the ability to access files in `www`.

The PDF's need to be initially bundled with the Application and will need to be updatable through the app if they get out of sync so I would like to be able to have them as part of the source and then copy them to the Documents folder to be manipulable/over-writable.

How do I copy Files from the `www` folder to the `Documents` folder? I imagine this is a common scenario but have had trouble finding examples of this online.

Any help appreciated.

Rickard

#### Update

So far I have been able to use file transfer to download files from a separate webserver:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer.download(
    'http://localhost:8080/data/output8.pdf',// This is a webserver I am running
    _fileSystem.root.fullPath+'/output8.pdf',
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }
);
```

So this is great if I wanted to download all the PDFs from a remote server but I need to download them from the `www` folder and I cant seem to find the path to do that. I have tried: `file:///data/output8.pdf` , `data/output8.pdf` and  `/data/output8.pdf`

What is the correct way to reference these paths?

#### Update 2 - Dead End Cannot Save as Binary

So I am still stuck on this hours later. I have gotten PDFjs rendering correctly but only from the files I serve from a webserver then FileTransfer to the local filesystem but not the files I bundle in with the application. I managed to load the file from www to an ArrayBuffer using XHR but cannot save it.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET','data/output8.pdf',true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e){
    var itWorked=this.status==0&&(this.response instanceof ArrayBuffer);
    console.log(itWorked?'looks like it worked':'hmm there was an issue: '+this.status);
    var myArrayBuffer = this.response;

    theFileSystem.root.getFile('output8.pdf',{create:true},function(entry){
        entry.createWriter(function(fileWriter){
          fileWriter.onwrite = function(){
            console.log('file has been written');
          };
            // Turns out the following does not work in 
            // Cordova which cannot write binary to a file.
            var blob = new Uint8Array(myArrayBuffer);
        fileWriter.write(blob);//Doesnt work
    },fail);
    },fail);                
}
xhr.ontimeout=function(e){
    console.log('timeout');
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Have you implemented Pdf.js in Cordova iOS ?

Comment: Not as of yet. I understand the issue with it not loading is likely due to files not being served through a webserver hence my attempt to load as Uint8Array via Cordova's FileAPI.

Comment: you can use FileTransfer

Comment: I am aware of that but what I am missing is how do I reference the source path though in the file transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a good night sleep I managed to solve the problem. The solution was to determine the relative absolute path and then **encode** the path URL as follows:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var relativeFileLocation = 'data/output8.pdf';
var fileSystemFileLocation = '/output8.pdf';
var docsPath = fileSystem.root.fullPath;
var wwwPath = docsPath.substring(0, docsPath.lastIndexOf('/'))+'/testios27.app/www/'
var filePath = wwwPath+relativeFileLocation;
fileTransfer.download(
    'file://'+encodeURI(filePath),
    theFileSystem.root.fullPath+'/output8.pdf', // Ouput path
    onTransferComplete,
    fail);
```

There are issues to this mainly that the path may need to be calculated differently for different platforms.

Comment: Where did **theFileSystem** and **fullPath** come from?

Answer (score 0):

answer to michal for how to get a full path.

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);function gotFS(fileSystem) {
alert("entered gotFS: " + fileSystem.root.fullPath);
}
```